# eslint indent rule indents decorated members

Tags: eslintrc, typescript-eslint

In order to enable indents for chained methods:

```
await PostModel
  .findOne({
    author: user.user,
    _id: id,
  })
  .populate('tickets', 'title status');
```

I have added the following `MemberExpression` to my eslintrc, as per [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent)

```
indent": ["error", "tab", { "MemberExpression": 1 }],
```

but now I am experiencing problem with decorators, which get indented although my preference is to have them aligned with the member.

```
@prop({ type: String, required: true })
  password: string;
```

Is there a way to address those two cases without a conflict?

Answer (score 25):

I got the same problem as you did, and found [this comment](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15299#issuecomment-968099681) help, give it a try?

```js
{
  rules: {
    // ...
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "ignoredNodes": ["PropertyDefinition"] }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1824#issuecomment-957559729), you can partially disable the indent rule for decorators:

```
indent: [
        'error',
        'tab',
        {
            MemberExpression: 1,
            ignoredNodes: [
                'FunctionExpression > .params[decorators.length > 0]',
                'FunctionExpression > .params > :matches(Decorator, :not(:first-child))',
                'ClassBody.body > PropertyDefinition[decorators.length > 0] > .key',
            ],
        },
    ],
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me at all. Seems though like there is an  ongoing unresolved problem with the indent rule causing many other tickets to get closed.

Answer (score 3):

@bujhmt's answer actually solved my problem, however, I needed to make some changes to it.

Before:

```html
export abstract class MyAbstractClass extends AnotherClass {
    @Column()
    name!: string;
    ^^^^--> Expected indentation of 8 spaces, found 4

    @Column()
    address!: string;
    ^^^^--> Expected indentation of 8 spaces, found 4
}
```

Then I changed my .eslintrc rule to this:

```
    "indent": [
        `error`,
        4,
        {
            "ignoredNodes": [
                `FunctionExpression > .params[decorators.length > 0]`,
                `FunctionExpression > .params > :matches(Decorator, :not(:first-child))`,
                `ClassBody.body > PropertyDefinition[decorators.length > 0] > .key`,
            ],
        },

    ],
```

And the errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can use `ignoredNodes` and use a Abstract Syntax Tree selector to ignore that specific element. That will mean that this element is no longer subject to the rule.

i.e.

```
Pass ✅
@prop({ type: String, required: true })
password: string;

Also Pass ✅
@prop({ type: String, required: true })
                      password: string;
```

You can paste code into https://astexplorer.net/ (if you are using typescript set type to `@typescript-eslint/parser` - see [helpful article here](https://www.darraghoriordan.com/2021/11/06/how-to-write-an-eslint-plugin-typescript/)

So something like this could help: `ClassBody.body > PropertyDefinition[decorators.length>0] > Identifier`

Which means any property on a class body with decorators will be ignored by the rule.