# vue class component props: Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 4 indent

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-class-components

I have vue class component like this

```
export default class MyText extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: String, default: 'id-rt' })
    id!: string; // ERROR: Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 4  indent
}
```

Should't the @Props and id! have the same indentention???

my eslint.cjs file

```
"extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended",
],
```

Whats causing that issue?

Note: If I remove `@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended` from extends then it worked. But I don't want to remove it, only want to disable the indentation issue for @Props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eslint indent rule indents decorated members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70642350/eslint-indent-rule-indents-decorated-members)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable checking for the indentation for the next line with:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line indent
```

Or for the whole file:

```js
// eslint-disable indent
```