# How to prevent es-lint from enforcing unnecessary tabs?

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

In my Angular project I would like to enforce tabs instead of spaces. That's why I added the following rule to my **.eslintrc.json**:

`"indent": ["error", "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1 }],`

This basically works, but it comes with an ugly side-effect: An additional indentation is enforced in the line below a decorator.

Therefore this is the **current formatting**:

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocomplete)
    autocomplete: MatAutocomplete; // This line should not be indented

@Input()
    value: string; // This line should not be indented
```

Yet this would be the **expected formatting**:

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocomplete)
autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

@Input()
value: string;
```

How can I achieve the expected formatting while keeping tabs (instead of spaces) as default?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to resolve my issue with the help of [this SO-article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70642350/eslint-indent-rule-indents-decorated-members).

I added the following lines to my **.eslintrc.json**:

```
"indent": ["error", "tab", { "ignoredNodes": [
            "FunctionExpression > .params[decorators.length > 0]",
            "FunctionExpression > .params > :matches(Decorator, :not(:first-child))",
            "ClassBody.body > PropertyDefinition[decorators.length > 0] > .key"
        ]}]
```